# Specific SQL with group by does not work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in my mysql database

```
+-----+----------+------+----------+
| id  | group_id | a_id | status   |
+-----+----------+------+----------+
|   2 |      144 |  266 | active   |
|   7 |      160 |  105 | inactive |
|   8 |        0 |  262 | inactive |
|  11 |      120 |  260 | inactive |
|  12 |      120 |  260 | inactive |
|  13 |      121 |  260 | active   |
|  14 |      122 |  258 | active   |
|  14 |      122 |  258 | inactive |
|  16 |      130 |  210 | active   |
|  17 |      130 |  210 | active   |
+-----+----------+------+----------+
```

I need to select a_id in such a way that all statuses in the same group (group_id) must be inactive and different from 0. What i want to obtain is actually an array of ids (105,260), from this table.

I came to this sql, but apparently it is not working correctly:

```
select a_id from tab_name where group_id<>0 and group_id in 
  (select group_id from tab_name where status="inactive" 
    group by group_id having status="inactive")
```

Comment: What's error you're getting? Usually in a group by you will need an aggregate function in the selects

Comment: a_id has a group_id 121 which has a status inactive. Should it be on your result set?

Comment: select a_id from tab_name where group_id!=0 and status="inactive" order by group_id, so I don't think there is need for grouping!

Comment: do you need to return also 260? group 120 is <> 0 and all inactive, but there's also group 121 which is active

Comment: and if there's a row with a_id=105 and group_id=0, you still need to return 105?

Comment: @fthiella - it is important that result will include all a_id's that have at least 1 group with with all statuses inactive. So Your answer match my request. Thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   DISTINCT a_id
FROM     yourtable
WHERE    group_id!=0
GROUP BY a_id, group_id
HAVING   SUM(status='inactive')=COUNT(*);
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2798d/6).

Comment: Nice! Much more elegant than my solution. +1

Comment: SQL fiddle, why didn't I know about this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you could use it easy like  this

```
   select a_id from tab_name where group_id<>0 and status="inactive" 
   group by group_id
```

update:

```
   select a_id from tab_name where group_id<>0 and status="active" 
  and a_id not in (select a_id from tab_name where status ='inactive')
   group by group_id
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15fd/23)

Comment: This will return 258 even though it is in a group that has a ro with status = "inactive"

Comment: The asker wants only a_ids for which *all* rows with the same group id are inactive.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
select a_id from tab_name where group_id<>0 and status="inactive"
```

Comment: In this case I will get also the id 258. because it has 2 rows- one active and one inactive. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, for your query, if there is a single inactive row then that group will be returned. Instead you can try a subquery that checks that there is no item in the group that is inactive or has a group_id of 0:

```
SELECT t1.a_id FROM tab_name t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT * FROM tab_name t2 
              WHERE t1.group_id = t2.group_id 
                 AND (t2.status = "inactive" OR t2.group_id = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to adjust your query slightly and use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`

Try this:

```
select a_id from tab_name where group_id<>0 and group_id in 
(select distinct group_id from tab_name where status="inactive")
```

Comment: There is no need for a `distinct` inside a sub-query that is used for an `IN` condition.

Comment: Ah yes, good spot, but would it not still have to move over more rows with same id?